# i have question about JWT-Authentication on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, authentication, jwt

hello i am getting this error can anybody resolve it

```
{"success":false,"statusCode":403,"code":"jwt_auth_no_auth_header","message":"Authorization header not found.","data":[]}
```

Comment: We need to see your code in order to be able to help, Ubaid. See: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ###
POST https://movies.2all.net/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/application/x-www-form-urlencoded

username=ubaid&password=ubaid123